# Visualize PLINK pedigree files

Tags: plink, pedigree

Is there a pedigree viewer that works with PLINK pedigree files? I saw an old post by [Pierre](https://www.biostars.org/p/60186/), but I don't see the script on his blog.

Comment: We use R package kinship2 here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kinship2/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `kinship2` R package to visualize pedigree files (.fam plink files). For some reasons, some characters from plink ped aren't supported (like "-9" for unknown genre or affected status).
Here is the R script we use:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
pedPath<-args[1]
pdfFile<-args[2]

library(kinship2)
pedfile <- read.table(pedPath,sep="\t")
pedfile$V5 <- apply(pedfile,1,function(data){if(data[5] == 1 || data[5] ==2){data[5]}else{3}}) 
pedfile$affected <- apply(pedfile,1,function(data){if(as.numeric(data[6]) == 1){res <- data[6]}else{if(as.numeric(data[6]) == 2){res <- data[6]}else{res <- NA}}})

familyIDs <- as.character(unique(pedfile$V1))

pdf(file=pdfFile)
for(famID in familyIDs){
    ped <- pedigree(id=as.character(pedfile$V2[pedfile$V1==famID]),dadid=as.character(pedfile$V3[pedfile$V1==famID]),momid=as.character(pedfile$V4[pedfile$V1==famID]),sex=as.numeric(pedfile$V5[pedfile$V1==famID]),affected=as.numeric(pedfile$affected[pedfile$V1==famID]))
    plot.pedigree(ped,cex=0.7,align=TRUE)
    title(famID)
}
```

And we call it this way:

```
Rscript <kinshipScript.R> <plink ped file> <pdf output>
```

Comment: Now, if only I could convince people to include affected information in the actual .fam files. :-)

Comment: @MarkEbbert affected status is not really necessary but it still looks good on the pdf :)